# How to let game users modify 3D image during the game?

Tags: modeling, game-engine, modifiers, 3d-view

I am a complete newbie to Blender and need advice, so please, bear with me.

This is my requirement: To make an object shape modifiable by game users. I.e. in a limited way, users should be able to change shape of the object and save the new object's state. What concerns me is that assets used in BGE at runtime are read-only and this seems to be a work that happens at design time. I would appreciate high level description how this can done in a standalone game using BGE.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question, What have you got so far? What have you tried? I'm not sure Blender game engine is capable of such complexity.

Comment: It certainly is capable of "such complexity." I would argue that a simple implementation of this is actually relatively easy.

Comment: Thanks guys, I narrowed the question down. This is my first time asking question by the way, so not sure how to remove it from hold :)

Comment: @sdfgeoff Nominated question for reopening, if it does care to elaborate a bit on how one could achieve such effect in an answer?

Comment: @AlexAl If you edit your question (as you already have) it will automatically be placed again on the review queue. If enough people vote for it, it will be reopened. Otherwise feel free to post a new question, but please keep in mind to ask specific and straight to the point question.

Comment: @Duarte You can change mesh with the replace mesh actuator, change color with the object color property, do mesh animations with armatures or shapekeys etc. Saving the state can be done with something like JSON or pickle module.

Comment: @sdfgeoff Thanks for the explanation! Do I understand correctly that all this can happen during the game and BGE (or BP Player) can process these user inputs and save state to the game?

Answer (score 1):

> change shape of the object

The question is "how do you change the shape of the object"?

Store the steps how to do that and do them again later.

For example:

You want to change the width of a wall. To do that you play a "width-changing" animation. To be more specific you play a specific pose of such an animation. This results in a wall with a different width.

The steps to get that shape are: Play pose x of the width.changing animation.

So you store this information (name of animation and frame of the pose).

On restore you can play this pose again.

Without further information on the how you want to change shape I can't provide further details.

I hope you get the idea.